# Ignore column name while imputation pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, imputation

I am trying to  use the KNNImputer Package to impute missing values into my dataframe. 
Here is my dataframe

```
pd.DataDrame(numeric_data)
```

> ```
>        age     bmi  children     charges
> 0      19     NaN       0.0  16884.9240
> 1      18  33.770       1.0         NaN
> 2      28  33.000       3.0   4449.4620
> 3      33  22.705       0.0         NaN
> ```

Here is when I pass the imputer package and output the dataframe.

```
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2, weights="uniform")
impute_data = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(numeric_data))
```

This gives:

> ```
>       0        1    2             3
> 0     19.0  34.0850  0.0  16884.924000
> 1     18.0  33.7700  1.0   6309.517125
> 2     28.0  33.0000  3.0   4449.462000
> 3     33.0  22.7050  0.0   4610.464925
> ```

How do I execute the same without losing my column name? Can I store the column name somewhere else and append later or can I impute with the column name being affected itself.

I have tried to exclude the column but I get the following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'age'

Comment: Does `impute_data = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(numeric_data), columns = numeric_data.columns)` not work? Or `columns = [list of columns names]`?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired result:-

```
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2, weights="uniform")
impute_data = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(numeric_data), columns=numeric_data.columns)
```